# Is there any kind of algebraic structure on a line in the hyperbolic plane?

Tags: plane-geometry, division-algebras

There is a very classical [correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plan) between projective planes and division algebras: given a plane, each choice of three distinct points (zero, one and infinity) on each line determines addition, subtraction, multiplication and division on points of this line with the infinity removed, and division algebras corresponding to all such choices are isomorphic. Furthermore associativity of multiplication corresponds to the Desargues axiom/theorem/property and commutativity to the Pappus axiom.

Is there a similar way to introduce any kind of algebraic structure on a line in the hyperbolic plane? It [seems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructions_in_hyperbolic_geometry) that accordingly rigged versions of most of the ordinary constructions are available in this case too (like, finding a line through a point parallel to two given lines). Besides, in the [Beltrami-Klein model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami%E2%80%93Klein_model) one has remnants of "ordinary" parallelism too.

[image]

Can one do something with that?

Comment: You can identify a line with $\mathbb R$, so I'm not quite sure what you mean, but perhaps this is the kind of thing you are looking for: you can identify the hyperbolic plane as PSL(2,R) mod SO(2).

Comment: @Kimball Sorry it is probably not clearly stated, but I mean algebraic operations that can be constructed using only axioms of geometry (like ruler and compass). As for your second identification - since SO(2) is not a normal subgroup of PSL(2,R), I do not see how to produce any algebraic operations on a line in the quotient. It is a promising observation, though: for example, if I want an addition, I must, for any (generic) point  $p$ on the chosen line, have the translation $p+(\_)$ and the dilation $p\cdot(\_)$ of the line. Maybe these can be produced from the PSL(2,R) homogeneous structure